# a string doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#

the following is a part of my code.

```
string lsStatus;
lsStatus = ((Tv10DBLookup)(Sender)).EditValue.ToString();
```

while im debuging the code, im getting the following: "lsStatus is not in the context" !

Knowing that (Tv10DBLookup)(Sender)).EditValue is returning the value "Closed"

what does this mean ?

Comment: Are you debugging retail or debug code and did you launch the process or attach?

Comment: Why does this have a `C++` tag? Is that C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the current stack frame is in a different method.

Double-click on the entry in the Call Stack window for the method that contains your variable.

Also, look at the Locals window.